# Confusion with on() method

Tags: jquery

doing my [lessons](http://try.jquery.com/levels/4/challenges/10) on codeschool, the following does not work

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
  $("#tour").on("click", "button", function() { 
    $(".photos").slideToggle();
  });
    $(".photos").on("mouseenter", "li", function() {
    $(this).find("span").slideToggle();

    $(".photos").on("mouseleave", "li", function() {
    $(this).find("span").slideToggle();
    });
  });
});
```

while the following is apparently correct.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
  $("#tour").on("click", "button", function() { 
    $(".photos").slideToggle();
  });
  $(".photos").on("mouseenter", "li", function() {
    $(this).find("span").slideToggle();

  })          .on("mouseleave", "li", function() {
    $(this).find("span").slideToggle();
  });
});
```

It looks to me as though they're simply taking a shortcut by leaving out the second `$(".photos")`. I can see how it might be inefficient to call something twice like that, but it's actually an error as well?

Comment: Look carefully through the code - your first example is structured differently in the nesting of the calls.

Comment: It would only be inefficient to call `$(".photos")` multiple times if the results stayed the same. If more `.photos` were added, then you need to call `$(".photos")` again to get up-to-date results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not an error, the problem is you are attaching a new `mouseleave` event handler on each `mouseenter` event.

```
$(".photos").on("mouseenter", "li", function() {
    $(this).find("span").slideToggle();

    // Here
    $(".photos").on("mouseleave", "li", function() {
        $(this).find("span").slideToggle();
    });
});
```

For minifying the code you can pass an object to the `on` method:

```
$(".photos").on({
   mouseenter: function() {
      $(this).find("span").slideToggle();
   },
   mouseleave: function() {
      $(this).find("span").slideToggle();
   }
}, 'li');
```

Comment: or in this case just `$(".photos").on('mouseenter mouseleave','li', function(){$(this).find("span").slideToggle();});`

Comment: Got it. I knew a missing }) would trip me up one day. Thanks